# Validando campo de formulario

Tags: javascript, jquery, formulário

Estou criando um formulário simples,em que tenho que fazer um calculo de dois campos para aparecer uma mensagem, até ai nenhum problema, mas como são varios campos que vou ter que aplicar mesma formula várias vezes, queria fazer de um jeito mais dinâmico, não apenas copiar o mesmo script várias vezes. Segue abaixo o meu código

```
<div class="col-4">
    <label for="habitantes" class="label">Número de Habitantes:</label>
    <input type="number" name="habitantes" id="habitantes">
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <label for="habitantes2" class="label">Número de Habitantes:</label>
    <input type="number" name="habitantes2" id="habitantes2">
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <label for="consultores" class="label">Número de Consultores Cadastrados</label>
    <input type="number" name="consultores[]" id="consultores">
    <span style="color:green" class="resultado"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <label for="consultores2" class="label">Número de Consultores Cadastrados</label>
    <input type="number" name="consultores[]" id="consultores2">
    <span style="color:green" class="resultado2"></span>
</div>

<script>
$('#consultores').change(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#consultores').each(function() {
            var valor = $('#habitantes').val();
            var valor2 = $('#consultores').val();
            var calculo = valor / valor2;
            if(calculo>=100){
                $('.resultado').html("deu certo");  
            }
        });
     });

    $('#consultores2').change(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#consultores').each(function() {
            var valor = $('#habitantes2').val();
            var valor2 = $('#consultores2').val();
            var calculo = valor / valor2;
            if(calculo>=100){
                $('.resultado2').html("deu certo"); 
            }
        });
     });
<script>
```

Comment: Aconselho te a usar uma lib de validação de formulários posso te aconselhar o uso http://formvalidation.io/examples/ ve os exemplos e a documentação

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 observações:

**1) `$('#consultores').each(function() {`**

Você não vai querer fazer laço em `id`s porque eles devem ser únicos, logo não faz sentindo fazer loop em um único elemento. Se você apagar o `.each` do seu código verá que o resultado é o mesmo.

**2) `event.preventDefault();`**

Não vi utilidade nesse `preventDefault()`. O evento `change` não é *cancelável*. Este método só deve ser usado em eventos *canceláveis* (como *click* e *submit*, por exemplo).

**3) `class="resultado"` e `class="resultado2"`**

Não faz sentido usar classes com nomes diferentes apenas para poder localizar o elemento. No código abaixo você nem precisará colocar classe nesses elementos porque você pode localizar a `span` com `.next()`, já que a `span` é o elemento logo após o campo `$("#consultores[n]")`.

Quanto ao código, pode fazer desta forma (veja explicações no código):

```
$('[id^="consultores"').change(function(){ // escuta os campos que possuem id começando com a palavra "consultores"

   var idx = $(this).attr("id").match(/\d+/); // pego apena a parte numérica da id
   idx = idx ? idx[0] : ''; // verifica se existe parte numérica. Se existe, pega, se não, retorna vazio

   var valor = $('#habitantes'+idx).val(); // concateno o idx para pegar o #habitantes + número
   var valor2 = $(this).val();  // pego o próprio valor do elemento alterado
   var calculo = valor / valor2;
   if(calculo>=100){
       $(this).next().html("deu certo"); // pego o elemento próximo e insiro o texto
   }
});
```

**Funcionando:**

```js
$('[id^="consultores"').change(function(){
   
   var idx = $(this).attr("id").match(/\d+/);
   idx = idx ? idx[0] : '';
   
   var valor = $('#habitantes'+idx).val();
   var valor2 = $(this).val();
   var calculo = valor / valor2;
   if(calculo>=100){
       $(this).next().html("deu certo");  
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="col-4">
    <label for="habitantes" class="label">Número de Habitantes:</label>
    <input type="number" name="habitantes" id="habitantes">
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <label for="habitantes2" class="label">Número de Habitantes:</label>
    <input type="number" name="habitantes2" id="habitantes2">
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <label for="consultores" class="label">Número de Consultores Cadastrados</label>
    <input type="number" name="consultores[]" id="consultores">
    <span style="color:green"></span>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <label for="consultores2" class="label">Número de Consultores Cadastrados</label>
    <input type="number" name="consultores[]" id="consultores2">
    <span style="color:green"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Mas e o resultado?

Comment: calculo ora pois pois

Comment: rsrs... ixi maria! Rs... ele quer uma função única que faça os cálculos e insira a frase "deu certo" no respectivo span... a pois, tá aí na resposta uma solução :D

Comment: $(this).next().html("deu certo e o valor é "+calculo)

Comment: Porque aquelas bibliotecas todas? so a jquery basta

Comment: É vdd, limites da pergunta e zefini. Dai só de pirraça não vai marcar como aceita, rs

Comment: As bibliotecas pra ficar mais bonitim